# Compilation error when using MVC 3 Membership : 'Models' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Security.Membership'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to follow a couple of tutorials on using the standard ASP.NET membership in MVC 3, as soon as I create an MVC 3 web application (Internet Application) in Visual Studio 2010 and I run the sample solution and click 'Log In' on the generated template I get an error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Security.Membership'

Line 28:     
Line 29:     public class _Page_Views_Account_LogOn_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Membership.Models.LogOnModel> {
```

I searched around but I can't seem to find any solutions. It's obviously something trivial, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your project name? is it Membership?

Comment: Ah Thanks. I changed it to something else and it works fine now, thanks. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/membership-and-authorization-in-Asp-Net-mvc-3-razor/) and the author advises to call the solution 'Membership'. Interesting bug.

Comment: @Morteza if you put your comment down as an answer I'll accept it. Unlikely coincidence as this may be, it can still be considered a a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your project name? is it Membership?

Error occurred because confuse between System.Web.Security.Membership and Membership (Project namespace )
Change project name